# Symfony 2 - FOSOAuthServerBundle - can we authorize manually?

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, oauth-2.0, fosoauthserverbundle

I'm trying to use FOSOAuthServerBundle. It works pretty well but I try to make it works in API... 
When I register a new user I create a new client and I would like to give him authorization directly. 
The request of the access_token will be done when the user will log in...

The problem, the example given in the documentation, it makes a redirection to an authorization page, and after it will redirect to an URL... 
It would be great to it without any redirection, only to make the authorization...

Part of my register code :

```
    $user->setUsername($name);
    $user->setEmail($email);
    $encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
    $password_user = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());
    $user->setPassword($password_user);

    $clientManager = $this->get('fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default');
    $client = $clientManager->createClient();
    $client->setRedirectUris(array('http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php'));
    $client->setAllowedGrantTypes(array('token', 'authorization_code'));
    $clientManager->updateClient($client);

    $user->setClient($client);

    // Here we would like to authorize the user witout redirection :
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_oauth_server_authorize', array(
                'client_id'     => $client->getPublicId(),
                'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php',
                'response_type' => 'code'
            )));
```

I would like to authorize without any redirection... Because it's in API :/ , so no URL... 
Is there another way to authorize ?

Thanks

Comment: How did you solve the issue?